# Can SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition be installed on Windows 7 Professional Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I want to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition to Windows 7 Professional Edition. I tried many times, but it also failed.

Is it possible to do that? Has anyone successfully installed SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7? What are the steps to guarantee a successful install?

Comment: Was there an error message or log entry that might shed more light on why it failed?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server Enterprise Edition does not support Windows client operating systems. You can only install it on Windows Server.

Try installing Developer Edition. It provides similar features with licensing restrictions (you can't install it on production servers).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed on Windows 7 Ultimate right now.  It may not be officially supported unless you're using Windows Server, but it does work.